# iOS app is not pulling data from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a function where it check for a child that is added in the database. If there is a child added, it sends an alert to screen saying accept or decline. I know there is a child added, but there's no alert.

```
  func observeMessagesForDriver() {
    // RIDER REQUESTED AN UBER
    DBProvider.Instance.requestRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.childAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        if let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            if let latitude = data[Constants.LATITUDE] as? Double {
                if let longitude = data[Constants.LONGITUDE] as? Double {
                    self.delegate?.acceptUber(lat: latitude, long: longitude);
                }
```

I added a breakpoint to the `if let` line and it never reach's there. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You have 3 `if let`. Which one isn't being reached?

Comment: the first one, sorry. I also put one on "Dbprovider.instance" and it skips over the rest of the if statements

Comment: It skips over the handler because it does not see that a child has been added.  I know you say that one has been added but based on the code you provided there really isn't much more than can be said.

Comment: Are you sure the user has permission to read the data. To detect this, follow the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/24788/detect-errors-when-reading-data-on-ios#t=201704030352142907962

Comment: does `requestRef` point to the right node in Firebase?

Comment: Please add a *print(snapshot)* as the first line inside the closure to see if any data is actually being returned and let us know.

Comment: Figured it out. my identifier was a letter off. Thanks guys